# How to count number of occurrences of a value in a map with Golang?

Tags: dictionary, go, sum

I have created a map with the following structure:

```
m := make(map[int]Record)
```

The Record is a struct as follows:

```
type Record struct {
    UID  int
    Type string
    Year string
}
```

The SumRecord struct is supposed to store information about the number of occurences of every given Type / Year Value in map m.

```
type SumRecord struct {
    Sum  int
    Type string
    Year string
}
```

The struct is supposed to hold information about book publication years, ie `{1, "Type": "fiction", "Year": 1996}, {2, "Type": "non-fiction", "Year": 1996}`

I am unsuccessfully trying to create a second map where I would store the sum of each publication type per year (similar to a SUM / GROUP BY in SQL). How can I achieve that with Go?

Comment: What is the key in the map `map[int]Record`, or is that unimportant?  What is the the key in the second map? Is it (year, type)?

Comment: The key in `map[int]Record` is just a counter (the Record entries come from an xml being parsed in an earler stage in the code), so it's not important. For the second map the key should be year, type (the `SumRecord` struct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution to the one provided by @ThunderCat.

This creates a new mapping of a SumRecord to an integer, representing the sum of occurrences for that specific grouping of Type/Year.

See full example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/zQi2HQEwerG).

```
type Record struct {
    UID  int
    Type string
    Year string
}

type SumRecord struct {
    Type string
    Year string
}

m := make(map[int]Record)

// e.g. [{"1996","non-fiction"}:4], representing 4 occurrences of {"1996","non-fiction"}
srMap := make(map[SumRecord]int)

// add records

// loop over records
for key := range m {
    sr := SumRecord{
        Type: m[key].Type,
        Year: m[key].Year,
    }
    // creates new counter or increments existing pair counter by 1
    srMap[sr] += 1
}
// print all mappings
fmt.Println(srMap)

// specific example
fmt.Println(srMap[SumRecord{
    Year: "1996",
    Type: "non-fiction",
}])
```